# Finding the login page from database?

Tags: database, login

long story short I was given the login information for an older gentleman who unfortunately passed away who managed a young lady's Wordpress website. Was asked to manage and update the site for the lady. I don't have a ton of experience in Wordpress, but hey.

Here's the issue. The site doesn't use any default login url's, both on it and its alias. I've been reading up on the Wordpress forums and I've seen mentions of looking in the database for the login url, but I haven't been able to find any mention of the url in the database, based on what I've read I'm supposed to be looking for.

So yea - can anybody at least point me in the right direction as to what I'm supposed to be looking for? Should I be looking in the database? I've already tried every default login page that I can physically find to no avail. Saw some people saying I should find id_login_base, couldn't find that. One person said to set id_hide_wp_admin to yup, which should make id_login_base show up. Neither worked. Halp. D:

Comment: Did you look at the plugins (folder)? Did you check the .htaccess file for any redirects?

Comment: Also please look at the active theme's functions.php file.

Comment: Most sites use a different login URL using a plugin or using a custom code in the theme (this is rare, though). That's why I asked you to look for any plugins in the plugins folder. It could be a security plugin too. Most all-in-one security plugins have the option to change the login URL too. And most plugins that do change the login URL, would write a piece of code in .htaccess file. So, try resetting .htaccess file to the default WP rewrites. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright! I understand that there is a custom wordpress login url. Also you need to login to a user's profile. If that's the case, I suggest a simple hack(If you legally have rights to access/modify the database). Try this:

1. Go to cpanel and login to phpmyadmin and open the database for your website/blog.
2. Find 'wp_options' table and search for a record 'active_plugins'. Now remove everything in the value to deactivate all plugins(Some plugin may have changed you login url, So this step.)
3. Then go to 'wp_users' table and you'll find all the user details here. You cannot change password as it is encrypted. So change the user email to a working email. Save the record.
4. Now go to the default wordpress login url(http//www.yourdomain/wp-admin). Press 'Lost password' and Enter the email you've entered for the user. You will get a confirmation email. Change the password. Done!

Reply if it worked!

Comment: It wouldn't work if the login URL is changed in the theme. Or if the htaccess file blocks the default WP login URLs.

Comment: You're awesome. Turns out that there was some plugin that the guy wrote that was randomizing the login url on a weekly basis. Disabling it let me use the standard wp-login.php link. I apologize, I forgot to mention that I already had the lady's login information, but I sincerely appreciate the thoroughness! Again, you're awesome.

Comment: Haha. Thanks. I'm glad that I could help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me when I tried to change the login url with a plugin called "Protect WP-Admin". after installing and activating I followed the instructions and tried to change the URL but it didn't work for me, even I was not able to login through usual login url.

Then I followed below steps.

1. Go to the Wordpress database that you mentioned during the
   installation process.
2. There will be table called wp_options (if you selected wp_ prefix
   during the installation for the tables)
3. Under the option_name column find the record name "active_plugins" it will be like this.

[image]

4. I removed this part for the String in the option_value column
   `i:0;s:37:"protect-wp-admin/protect-wp-admin.php"`
5. Then I saved the record that and restarted my apache server.

I was able to login to the usual http://site_name/wp-admin URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPS hide login plugin and forgot the login route:

Connect to the database `mysql -u myUser -p`

```
use wordpressDatabase;

SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name="rwl_page";
```

the `option_value` is the path to your admin

`myblog.com/option_value/` << login